# I can't browse server files with Django Ckeditor

Tags: django, amazon-s3, ckeditor, digital-ocean

I build a django application. I use DigitalOcean space to store my media files. I use Django Ckeditor to allow admin to write content with nice textarea and to allow them to upload some images.

Uploading image is working (in the folder : "`modules_images`" as you can see in my code).
Problem happen's when admin want to click on the button "browse server". He get the following error :

```
NoSuchKey at /ckeditor/browse/
An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the ListObjects operation: Unknown
```

I spent a lot of time looking for people who already meet this problem but no one had exactly the same (people who meet problems at browsing files generally meet problems at uploading files too) and no one of the answers helped me.

Here is my urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [

    ...

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls, name="admin"),
    path('chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Here is my ckeditor configs in settings.py :

```
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "modules_images/"
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'skin': 'moono',
        # 'skin': 'office2013',
        'toolbar_Basic': [
            ['Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic']
        ],
        'toolbar_YourCustomToolbarConfig': [
            {'name': 'document', 'items': ['Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates']},
            {'name': 'clipboard', 'items': ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo']},
            {'name': 'editing', 'items': ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt' ]},
            {'name': 'forms',
             'items': ['Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton',
                       'HiddenField']},
            '/',
            {'name': 'basicstyles',
             'items': ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Strikethrough', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'CopyFormatting', 'RemoveFormat']},
            {'name': 'paragraph',
             'items': ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-',
                       'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl',
                       'Language']},
            {'name': 'links', 'items': ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor']},
            {'name': 'insert',
             'items': ['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe']},
            '/',
            {'name': 'styles', 'items': ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize']},
            {'name': 'colors', 'items': ['TextColor', 'BGColor']},
            {'name': 'tools', 'items': ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks']},
            {'name': 'about', 'items': ['About']},
            '/',  # put this to force next toolbar on new line
            {'name': 'yourcustomtools', 'items': [
                # put the name of your editor.ui.addButton here
                'Preview',
                'Maximize',

            ]},
        ],
        'toolbar': 'YourCustomToolbarConfig',  # put selected toolbar config here
        # 'toolbarGroups': [{ 'name': 'document', 'groups': [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] }],
        # 'height': 291,
        # 'width': '100%',
        # 'filebrowserWindowHeight': 725,
        # 'filebrowserWindowWidth': 940,
        # 'toolbarCanCollapse': True,
        # 'mathJaxLib': '//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.2-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML',
        'tabSpaces': 4,
        'extraPlugins': ','.join([
            'uploadimage', # the upload image feature
            # your extra plugins here
            'div',
            'autolink',
            'autoembed',
            'embedsemantic',
            'autogrow',
            # 'devtools',
            'widget',
            'lineutils',
            'clipboard',
            'dialog',
            'dialogui',
            'elementspath'
        ]),
    }
}
```

And here is my Space configs in settings.py :

```
# SETTINGS FOR S3 SPACE
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '<key_id>'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '<secre_access_key>'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = '<bucket_name>'
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = 'https://<bucket_name>.<region_name>.digitaloceanspaces.com/'
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False

MEDIA_URL = AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL
MEDIA_ROOT = AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

And of course 'ckeditor' and 'ckeditor_uploader' are in my INSTALLED_APPS

I can't see what I'm doing wrong in this process. If someone could help me it would be great
Thank's for reading

Comment: is anyone able to solve this issue?